# why Specialized template class need forward declaration?

Tags: c++, templates

such is the code:

```
template<typename,int> class Uoo;  //without this will result in complie error,why?

template<typename T>
class Uoo<T,1>
{
};

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

why  Specialized template class need forward declaration?

Comment: What would that specialisation actually, well, specialise? To specialise something, there has to be something 'general' that can be specialised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is a *specialisation* of a template.

```
template<typename T>
class Uoo<T,1>
{
};
```

But you haven't said what the unspecialised form is, and the language requires you to do that. So you need to add the prototype:

```
template<typename,int> class Uoo;
```

You don't actually need to *declare* the unspecialised form since an instance of it is never required. So a prototype is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually a forward declaration that you're making. What you are doing is first defining the "pattern" of the templated class and *then* you're defining a specialized context or version of it. The better question is, if you *didn't* have a non-specialized case, then what would be the point of the 2nd template parameter?

Answer (score 0):

As declared, `template<typename T> class Uoo<T,1>` is a partial specialization of `template<typename,int> class Uoo`; it fixes the int parameter to 1. It cannot be a partial specialization of a template that doesn't exist.

You could make your "real" class template self-sufficient by writing

```
template<typename T>
class Uoo
{
...
};
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean by making the template class *self-sufficient*. His original class requires two template arguments.

Comment: Not needing another class. The only case defined in the original code fixes the int template parameter to 1, so there is no need for it to be a template parameter. Only the typename parameter is required, and two classes are redundant.